# change selected radio button textcolor in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the text color on the selected radio button's text when it is checked ( a group of three). It doesn't work. I've tried multiple variations but this should be working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (
    $('.radioPanel [input:radio]').is(":checked")) {
        $(this).css('color', '#008000');
    }
});
```

Here is the aspx code; is the outer code affecting the jquery changes?

```
<fieldset class="registerradio">
                    <legend>Select a Category</legend>
                  <asp:Panel ID="radiobtnPanel" runat="server" CssClass="radioPanel">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="radioUserEmployee" runat="server" GroupName="radioCreateUsers" Text="Employee" TextAlign="Left"  />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="radioUserDistributor" runat="server" GroupName="radioCreateUsers" Text="Distributor" TextAlign="Left"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="radioUserCustomer" runat="server" GroupName="radioCreateUsers" Text="Existing Customer" TextAlign="Left"/>
                    <%--<asp:RadioButton ID="radioUserOther" runat="server" GroupName="radioCreateUsers" Text="Other" TextAlign="Left"/>--%>
                  </asp:Panel>
 </fieldset>
```

Here is the fiddle;
    http://jsfiddle.net/6yVL3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were some errors in your JavaScript :

- You set mootools instead of jQuery in jsFiddle
- Your selector was wrong, it's `[attr=value]`, check the list [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)
- Your JavaScript was static, it means that you check just once if the radio was checked, if there was changes, nothing happen
- You set the color to the radio and not the label

Here is the code :

```
$(function() {
    // When the value of the radio change
    $('.radioPanel [type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
        $(this)
        .prev().css('color', 'red')
        .siblings().css('color', 'black');
    });
});​
```

And here is [the live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/6yVL3/33/).

Comment: Calvein, this works great in the fiddle but not on my aspx page

Comment: Show us the HTML so, the <label>s need to be just before the <input>s and the <input>s need to be in a big .radioPanel element.

Comment: I suggest use `.siblings('label')` instead of pur `.siblings()` because every input is applied `color:black` in your solution.

Comment: @ComboZhc Every element, in this case it's not important because the only non-label element are radio but yes, i you have more element @dinotom, add 'label' to `siblings`.

Comment: I edited my original post to show the aspx code, the html in my fiddle was generated from that

Comment: well, the other answer bailed and deleted his responses, not sure why.

Comment: Do you see anything in the aspx code that could be affecting the way this is working?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.radioPanel input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        $(this).prev('label').css('color', '#008000');
});​
```

By the way, you should remove the color of the label previously checked. Like this:

```
$('.radioPanel input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('.radioPanel label').css('color', 'black');
    //This in result removes the color of the label checked previously, in fact it just resets all the color of labels to black
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
       $(this).prev('label').css('color', 'green');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6yVL3/46/).

Answer (score 1):

You may try like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6yVL3/43/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".radioPanel :input:checked").prev('label').css('color', '#008000');

});​
```